# How to make multiple conditional AJAX requests

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm having a database with 3 tables, a HTML and a PHP file.

Database:
tbl_customers

```
+---------+-----------+
|  ID     | Name      | 
+---------+-----------+
| 1       |Customer_1 |
+---------+-----------+
|   ...   |   ...     |
+---------+-----------+
```

tbl_data

```
+---------+---------+------+
|  ID     | Data 1  | C_ID |
+---------+---------+------+
| 1       |1        | 1    |
+---------+---------+------+
|   ...   | ...     |...   |
+---------+---------+------+
```

and so on...

My HTML Output

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="tbl_customers">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Customer-ID</th>
            <th>Customer Name</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Customer_1</td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" id="set" type=
            "button">Select</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Customer_2</td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" id="set" type=
            "button">Select</button></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- ... -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Made with the following AJAX:

```
$(function () 
{
  $.ajax({                                      
    url: 'db-api.php',              //the script to call to get data          
    data: "",                       //you can insert url argumnets here to pass to db-api.php
                                    //for example "id=5&parent=6"
    dataType: 'json',               //data format      
    success: function(data)         //on recieve of reply
    {

        var output_customers= $("#tbl_customers");

        for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            $("<tr><td>"+data[i][0]+"</td><td>"+data[i][1]+"<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' id='set''><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-download'></span> Select</button></td></tr>").appendTo(output_customers);
        }
    } 
  });
});
```

My db-api.php

```
<?php 
    $host = "127.0.0.1";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "";
    $db = "pd_dev_01";


    $tbl_data = "data";
    $tbl_customers = "customers";

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // 2) Connection to DB
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
    $dbs = mysql_select_db($db, $con);

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // 3) SQL
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_customers");     // Query
    $array = array();                                       // Array erzeugen
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {                       
        $array[] = array($row[0], $row[1]);                                 
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // 4) Output as JSON 
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

In my HTML I do an AJAX request of my PHP file to get all customer names (select * from tbl_customers). 
What I want is, that the user now can click on the result and **I perform another request to get all records from tbl_data with the same customer-ID of tbl_customers.**

How would I accomplish that?

Comment: Could you paste your HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's many ways to accomplish this. One way is you can put the customer id on a data attribute on the row you print out and use that to perform your query.

HTML

```
<tr data-customer-id="4">...</tr>
```

Javascript

```
$('table').on('click', 'tr[data-customer-id]', function () {

  var $tr = $(this),
      id = $tr.data('customer-id');

  $.get('/customer', { id: id }, function (customer) {
    $tr.after('<tr><td>' + customer.name + '</td></tr>')
  });

});
```

Then in your PHP you can use a sanitized version of `$_GET['id']` to perform your queries.

Comment: looks promising. So I need to add 'data-customer-id="data[i][0]"' to my jQuery. How would I change my db-api.php in order to perform the new SQL query?

Comment: I already have the customer name with my AJAX request (see above). What I need is another query based on the user selection of the customer. lets say customer_2 is selected, all records with c_ID = 2 from table_data should be loaded into my local storage as an json array -> array[[2,asd],[2,efg],[2,hij]].

Comment: Why do you want to save it to localStorage? That seems like an unneeded step to take.

Comment: sorry, its just my next step. The first important thing is to retrieve the data.

Comment: Your PHP file should return like... `echo json_encode($resultsFromDatabase)` then you can go through it like you want.

Comment: I added my PHP. I'm totally new to PHP. Hope this looks fine.

Comment: You have to adjust your SQL query to include a where for that particular customer and you GET the id from the AJAX called with `$_GET['id']`.

Comment: I know, but how? I have the following Problem: The first query is called to load the customer names. Then the user picks one from the html table by clicking on it. Now I need to call another query, based on the ID in another database-table, right? No idea how to accomplish that.

Comment: I made it work by setting up a second php file with my new query. Would that be still possible in one single php file?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that on a single ajax request.

Fetch all records in a single query with concate of Data 1. 
Query is

Select C.name,C.id,GROUP_CONCAT(D.data1  SEPARATOR '#') AS ddata1  from tbl_customers C inner join tbl_data D ON C.id = D.C_id Group by D.id;